# ClearCase (8.0.1.23) for 8.0.1 not coming in IBM IM to install

Tags: version-control, clearcase

Current Clearcase verion is `8.0.1.19` With `IBM Installation Manager - 1.8.8` tried to update the clearcase version to 8.0.1.23(Latest), Whereas through `IBM Installation Manager` says that there is no new update available and it already up-to-date. Does it officially not allowed to install?

Answer (score 2):

New ClearCase fixpacks have not been available via the IBM service repositories for at least a year. You need to download them via Fix Central, which requires an IBM account.

Please also note that ClearCase 8.0.1 has been out of support for at least 2 years.

Do not update to IM 1.9.x while using CC 8.0.1 as that combination is not tested. There are issues with installing older 9.0.x releases using IM 1.9, so we can assume that there will be for CC 8.

Comment: @Brain Cowan,  Yes '8.0.1.19 to 8.0 1.23' fix packs seems not included in repository to install through IM update option and via internet. So already tried to download '8.0.1.23' fix with my IBM account(My account is not license subscription account) it is just an normal IBM account but It was showing above errors.

Comment: The 8.0.1 and 9.0.x fixpacks are only available to customers with current Service and Support subscriptions. Also, technically, the 8.0.1 fixpacks should only be available to customers with "extended support" Entitlements. (They are currently available to all customers with support subscriptions...) If you're using an IBM account not "attached" to your customer account, you need to either create one, or associate the IBM account with your service subscription.

Comment: @Brain Cowan, Since we are running Clearcase on CentOS and Since last 3 years we have not renewed our IBM Support subscription. Hence it looks it is not letting to download. Even tried with another normal user account result is same.`Some selected fixes encountered errors for this order.

No applicable IBM support agreement found for one or more of the products you selected.`

Comment: If it is allowed to download after renewing the `Extended Support Entitlements` then we will need to migrate our VOB data to Gerrit (OR) GitLab.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the state of [IBM Installation Manager](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/installation-manager-and-packaging-utility-download-documents), I would start and upgrade it to 1.9.x first:

> Note the pre-1.9 versions of the IBM Installation Manager and IBM Packaging Utility components have been superseded and are no longer available for download from ibm.com.
>
> You should update your pre-1.9 components with the most recent version available.

Then I would see if an up-to-date IM has access to all latest versions of IBM products, like the [march 2020 fix pack ClearCase 8.0.123](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/rational-clearcase-fix-pack-23-80123-801).

---

The error "Some selected fixes encountered errors for this order" suggests, as shown in [this technote](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/downloading-fixes-ibm-fix-central-results-entitlement-failure):

[image: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/system/files/support/swg/rattech.nsf/0/b953bca5cabf53a6852578ea005b660b/Symptom/0.1F6.jpg]

> ### Cause:
>
> There may be two primary causes:
>
> - You are not eligible for the product
> - Cookies in your browser hold incorrect information

So if cleaning all cookies from your browser does not solve it... contacting the eCustomer Care is the recommended action.

Comment: Upgraded my `IM` to `1.9.1.4 (Architecture-64-Bit)` but still i could see only `8.0.1.19` to install, through internet i am trying to upgrade.

Comment: @Kishore Can you try and upgrade to 8.0.1.19 first (That is CC8.0.1.8 as shown in https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/whats-new-clearcase-0), and then try again and see if 8.0.1.23 is proposed then?

Comment: Tried that method, still same result.

Comment: @Kishore At this point, I would contact IBM support to understand why this particular fix pack is not available. Maybe the URL has changed?

Comment: Okay. sure. would be helpful thanks a lot.

Comment: Tried to download the particular fix `8.0.1.23 & 8.0.1.22.zip` files but both saying below message.

`Some selected fixes encountered errors for this order.
No applicable IBM support agreement found for one or more of the products you selected.`

Comment: @Kishore OK, I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: It looks from `8.0.1.20` fix on-wards active subscription required to download even fix pack, Since we have not renewed our subscription and hence we are not eligible to download the fix.  Thanks VonC for the support.

Comment: @Kishore Makes sense indeed.